# Can't connect to Snowflake via unixODBC and R

Tags: sql, r, database, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect to a Snowflake database via R and unixODBC but keep getting the error below, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to move forward.

```
[IM004][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed
```

I installed unixODBC and the Snowflake ODBC driver on my M1 Mac (I think this might be part of the problem?) as per Snowflake's documentation and running the command `odbcinst -j` in a terminal gives the expected output.

However, if I try to run `isql -v <DSN>` in a terminal to test the connection, I get the error above. I get the same error if I try to connect via R with the `odbc` package, or via RStudio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I have tried the solution from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652761/error-loading-snowflake-odbc-driver-on-mac-m1-from-erlang-call-odbc-connect), with no success. I've also seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71790445/3358272) but that involves installing the x86_64 version of R, RStudio, and the ODBC driver, which also didn't work.

Comment: Please refer another similar post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652761/error-loading-snowflake-odbc-driver-on-mac-m1-from-erlang-call-odbc-connect

Comment: If you look a few links into that link, you'll find https://stackoverflow.com/a/71790445/3358272, where the author claims to have snowflake odbc working on mac's M1.

Comment: I have tried both of these solutions, and neither works.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?

Comment: @SrinathMenon - nope, not yet.